# Why am I getting a null error when using an XML file with my servlet

Tags: java, xml, servlets, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I have a DAO which makes use of an xml file as a pseudo-database. This is my DAO Class:

```
package com.bootcamp.webapps.DAOs;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.bootcamp.webapps.beans.DragonBean;
import com.bootcamp.webapps.beans.DragonDatabaseBean;

public class DragonDAO {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DragonDAO.class);
    private List<DragonBean> dragonsList;
    private DragonDatabaseBean dragonDatabase;


    public DragonDAO() {
    }


    private void getDragonsFromDatabase()  {
        try {
            File file = new File("dragonDatabase.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(DragonDatabaseBean.class);
            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            dragonDatabase = (DragonDatabaseBean) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            dragonsList = dragonDatabase.getDragonsList();
            System.out.println("dragonListSize: " + dragonsList.size());
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            logger.debug("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.debug("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
        } 
    }


    public Logger getLogger() {
        return logger;
    }


    public List<DragonBean> getDragonsList() {
        getDragonsFromDatabase();
        return dragonsList;
    }


}
```

What's weird is that when I use a main method and make use of getDragonsFromDatabase() method (after adding the static keyword to the necessary places in my code), it seems to work. My log4j just shows this message though:

```
2016-01-04 11:05:27 DEBUG DragonDAO:34 - ERROR: null
```

Comment: Don't use a `File`. Search for how to read "resources" or "classpath resources". Something should pop up.

Comment: So the File object is the problem then? Does that mean that in web apps I should avoid using that object?

Comment: Pretty much. Put the file at the root of the classpath, and use `DragonDAO.class.getResourceAsStream("/dragonDatabase.xml")`. This will return an `InputStream`. This should work for both the standalone and webapp. You can pass the InputStream to the unmarshall method

Comment: Does this mean I'll be unmarshalling the InputStream object?

Comment: Yup!... _"You can pass the InputStream to the unmarshall method "_